# how to format asp.net panel beside one another

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="469px" Width="152px">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#666666" Height="363px" 
Width="533px">
</asp:Panel>
```

Hey atm my asp panels are one ontop of the other how do I make it so both are side by side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a CssClass to both and float them right and display:inline in the css.
asp.net panels basiclly render to spans or divs and can be styled as such.

Comment: Are you sure they fit inside thier container side by side?

Answer (score 2):

Mix inside html?

```
<table><tr><td>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="469px" Width="152px"> </asp:Panel> 
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#666666" Height="363px"  Width="533px"> </asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr></table>
```